# How to specify available time for Shiny App usage

Tags: r, shiny

I made a Shiny App which basically teaches students about simple statistic tests and plots. However, because (an while) I have a free account on [shiny](https://www.shinyapps.io/), I have a limited amount of time to make it available per month. Therefore, I'm going to set specific windows of time for it to run every week. The thing is I can't manually do it every time, not only because I'd likely forget, but because I'm not available during the closing time (17h) to do it. Also, I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Therefore, I wanted to know if there was a way to automate available times for the Shiny App to be open and possibly running, and to have the link be useless at any other time.

I realise I've only written things here, so if I forgot any important information, please ask and I'll edit this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `reactiveTimer` to check regularly time, use a `modalDialog` if the time is over to warn the user, and stop the App after a few seconds:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(actionButton("run", "Do something")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Check time every minute
  time <- reactiveTimer(60000)
  observe({
    currenthour <- as.numeric(format(time(), '%H'))
    if (currenthour >= 17) {
      showModal(modalDialog(title = "App not available after 17h",
                            paste("it's", format(time(), '%H:%M'), "h, please try again tomorrow")))
      Sys.sleep(5)
      stopApp()
    }
  })
})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]